# Rails. Update model attributes on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes, callback

Thought it's an easy task however I have stuck a little bit with this issue:

Would like to update one of the attributes of the model whenever it's saved, thus having a callback in the model:

```
after_save :calculate_and_save_budget_contingency

def calculate_and_save_budget_contingency
  self.total_contingency = self.budget_contingency + self.risk_contingency
  self.save
  # => this doesn't work as well.... self.update_attribute :budget_contingency, (self.budget_accuracy * self.budget_estimate) / 1
end
```

And the webserver shoots back with the message `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SystemStackError: stack level too deep: INSERT INTO "versions"`

Which basically tells me that there is an infite loop of save to the model, `after_save` and then we save the model again... which goes into another loop of `saving` the model

Just stuck at this point of time on this model attribute calculation. If anyone has encountered this issue, and has a nice nifty/rails solution, please shoot me a message below, thanks

Comment: Infinite Recursion. You're calling save during an after_save operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to following

```
before_save :calculate_and_save_budget_contingency

def calculate_and_save_budget_contingency
  self.total_contingency = self.budget_contingency + self.risk_contingency
end
```

Reason for that is - if you run save in `after_save` you end up in infinite loop: a save calls after_save callback, which calls save which calls after_save, which...

In general it's wise you use after save only for changing associated models, etc.

Comment: And from this `INSERT INTO "versions"` I gather you have also some versioning in place?

Answer (score 1):

Try before_save or before_validation, but don't include the .save

Comment: Mate, you probably don't know what are you writting about.. Have a look at Rails Model callbacks.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save

Comment: Uhh.. wtf.  The solution that you marked as correct did exactly the same thing.  He switched to before_save, and the method doesn't call self.save.  That's exactly what I suggested, and you downvote me and tell me I don't know what I'm writing about?

Comment: @bratsche strange, it's same solution. upvoted your answer =)

Comment: Guys, if you would check what was written in the question and the answer you would understand why the solution provided by bratsche is wrong

Comment: @bratsche, yes, mate, you are right he used before_save and didn't call `self.save` which seems for me an issue

Comment: So basically you downvote me, condescend to me, then see that I did answer your question but don't bother to undo your downvote. Thanks.